# how to pass three variables in url in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Route::get('reports/{reports}/leave', ['as'=> 'reports.leave', 'uses' =>'ReportController@leave']);

@foreach($dat as $report)

```
    <?php 
         $date=$_POST['date']; 
         $fdate=$_POST['fdate'];
          ?>
        <td><a href="{{ URL::route('admin.reports.leave',$report->name,$fdate) }}">{!!$report->name!!}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass three variable you can try the following example code:

Route:

```
Route::get('admin/{variable_1}/reports/{variable_2}/leave/{variable_3}', 'ReportController@leave');
```

Controller method :

```
public function leave($variable_1, $variable_2, $variable_3){

}
```

HTML (blade) link :

```
<a href="{{ url('admin/'.$variable_1.'/reports/'.$variable_2.'/leave/'.$variable_3) }}">{!!$report->name!!}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below given code:
**Route**

```
Route::get('reports/{reports}/leave/{date}/{fdate}', [
'as'=> 'reportsLeave', 'uses' =>'ReportController@leave']);
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($dat as $report)
<?php 
    $date=$_POST['date']; 
    $fdate=$_POST['fdate'];
    ?><td><a href="{{ URL::route('reportsLeave',[$reports => $report->name, 'date' => $date, 'fdate' => $fdate) }}">{!!$report->name!!}</td>
```

**Controller**

```
public function leave($reports, $date, $fdate){...}
```

Hope above suggested way will work for you. Best of Luck!